# @media padding not working

Tags: css, media, padding

I am having problems with @media and padding my navigation. When I just do the last @media, `@media (min-width: 992px)` it works fine, but nothing happens when I add the other arguments in. Here is what I am doing:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #navigation ul li a { padding: 15px 20px; }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  #navigation ul li a { padding: 15px 20px; }
}
@media (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  #navigation ul li a { padding: 15px 30px; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #navigation ul li a { padding: 15px 24px; }
}
```

Thanks for having a look

Comment: For a start, use proper syntax, like this: `@media screen and (max-width: 767px) { }`. See if that helps.

Comment: No dice. Even if I put `@media only screen and` or just `@media screen and`

Comment: @ralph.m: There is nothing wrong with or improper about the given syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in my Mac Chrome. Also, vertical padding doesn't work on `<a>` elements, but it will on `<li>` elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <style>
        @media (max-width: 767px) {
            #navigation ul li a {
                color: red;
                padding: 0;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
            #navigation ul li a {
                color: green;
                padding: 10px 5px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 991px) {
            #navigation ul li a {
                color: yellow;
                padding: 20px 15px;
            }
        }

        @media (min-width: 992px) {
            #navigation ul li a {
                color: blue;
                padding: 30px 25px;
            }
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="google.com">Google</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```